# RegEx Pattern Matching

Tags: c#, regex

Here's the Pattern:

```
((?<active>\*\s)*(fcid\s(?<fcid>0x[0-9a-f]{6})\s)*\[)?pwwn\s(?<pwwn>(([0-9a-f]{2}:){7})[0-9a-f]{2})(]\s\[(?<alias>\w*))*
```

Here's the possible input - each of those would be a line:

```
 1/ *fcid 0xce36c3 [device-alias N2F07D08]
 2/ pwwn c0:50:76:04:52:7e:00:2b [ARAH2KDBP04_STA_2b]
 3/ *fcid 0x19176a  [pwwn c0:50:76:04:52:7e:00:2a] [ARAH2KDBP04_STA_2]
```

It currently matches lines 2 and 3.  I need it to match the first line also.  I am having issues getting what is in the second line as optional.  If I try to make it optional, then the last 2 lines don't match either.  I know I don't have anything in the pattern yet to match the device-alias line but I am trying to get the input in the second line as optional first.

Comment: something is missing..cant understand ur question

Comment: try now.  I made some edits to fix formatting.

Comment: you should give more info about your input.. **Do you want to match only those 3 inputs**

Comment: This does not match the whole lines, just parts of them and incoherently so. What exactly do you need to pull out from these lines?

Comment: for this part of the file I am parsing, yes. Those are the 3 possible inputs.  I could split the pattern up but would rather try to get it all in one match, that way I can test each line once. Those are the possible inputs, each line will contain one of those 3.

Comment: @DavidGreen this would match them all

`(fcid|pwwn).?(0x[0-9a-f]{6}|[a-f0-9:]{23}).?\[(.*)\]`

Comment: In the fist line, I need to match the leading asterisk (if there is one) the 6 characters after the 0x, and any number of characters after device-alias, stopping at the closing ]  in the second line I need what is between pwwn and the opening [ excluding spaces.  in the last line I need the leading asterisk, the 6 characters after 0x and then the same as the second line

Comment: @DavidGreen Check out the expression here http://gskinner.com/RegExr/?31ulg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is **ugly**

```
((\*\s*)?fcid\s*0x\w{6}\s*\[(device-alias.*?|pwwn\s\w{2}(\:\w{2}){7})\]|pwwn\s\w{2}(\:\w{2}){7})
```

works [here](http://regexhero.net/tester/)

Comment: thanks so much.  it didn't work here:  http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ - that is the site I have been using. I assumed it was that site I have been using so  I wrote a quickie app in C# and tested, it works there.

Comment: @DavidGreen - That's pretty common.  RegExr uses the ActionScript regex engine and Regex Hero uses the .NET regex engine.  And there are differences / incompatibilities between the two engines.

Answer (score 2):

it doesn't match the first line because the regexp requires `pwwn` information to be present.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex with IgnoreCase and MultiLine options checked and your named groups:

```
^(?<active>\*\s?)*(?:fcid\s(?<fcid>0x[0-9a-f]{6})\s+)?(?:\[?pwwn\s(?<pwwn>(?:[0-9a-f]{2}:){7}[0-9a-f]{2})\]?\s+)?\[(?<alias>[^[]+)\]$
```

You can test this here at [RegexHero](http://regexhero.net/tester/?id=acf33813-58d5-47d6-91e1-3066687f6afa)

The C# code could be:

```
string strRegex = @"^(?<active>\*\s?)*(?:fcid\s(?<fcid>0x[0-9a-f]{6})\s+)?(?:\[?pwwn\s(?<pwwn>(?:[0-9a-f]{2}:){7}[0-9a-f]{2})\]?\s+)?\[(?<alias>[^[]+)\]$";
RegexOptions myRegexOptions = RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline;
Regex myRegex = new Regex(strRegex, myRegexOptions);
string strTargetString = @"*fcid 0xce36c3 [device-alias N2F07D08]\npwwn c0:50:76:04:52:7e:00:2b [ARAH2KDBP04_STA_2b]\n*fcid 0x19176a  [pwwn c0:50:76:04:52:7e:00:2a] [ARAH2KDBP04_STA_2]";

foreach (Match myMatch in myRegex.Matches(strTargetString))
{
  if (myMatch.Success)
  {
    // Extract your named groups here
  }
}
```